# Vue.js公式サンプルのグリッドコンポーネントで、行にマウスオーバーイベントを設定する

Tags: vue.js

Vue.jsでマウスオーバーイベントをハンドリングする方法について質問です。

やりたいこと
グリッドコンポーネントのサンプルプログラムで、
行にマウスオーバーすると行の色が変化する。
https://jp.vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html

やったこと

```js
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function() {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    },
    mouseover: function(event) {
      alert(event.target);
      alert(event.target.textContent);
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [{
      name: 'Chuck Norris',
      power: Infinity
    }, {
      name: 'Bruce Lee',
      power: 9000
    }, {
      name: 'Jackie Chan',
      power: 7000
    }, {
      name: 'Jet Li',
      power: 8000
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

#search {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.js"></script>
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
          {{key | capitalize}}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]" @mouseover="mouseover">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search
    <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid :data="gridData" :columns="gridColumns" :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

html側のtr要素に@mouseoverイベントを追加しましたが、
javascript側でevent.targetのプロパティを見てもtdが返ってきます。
当然tdのスタイルを変更してもマスの色しか変わりません。
行全体の色を変更するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

HTML側

```
   <tr v-for="
    entry in data
    | filterBy filterKey
    | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]" @mouseover="mouseover">
```

js側

```
mouseover: function(event) {
  alert(event.target);
  alert(event.target.textContent);
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/38051　マルチポスト

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` を使って下さい。

簡単に言うと、
イベントが発生した要素(`event.target`)と、
イベントをキャッチした要素(`event.currentTarget`)の
2種類ある、ということです。

イベントバブリングについてお調べになると、理解が深まると思います。
[DOMイベントのキャプチャ/バブリングを整理する 〜 JSおくのほそ道 #017 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/hosomichi/items/49500fea5fdf43f59c58)

なお、やりたいことが、行全体の色を変えるだけでしたら、私なら css を書くと思います。

```
tr:hover td {
  background-color: red
}
```

```js
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function() {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    },
    mouseover: function(event) {
      //alert(event.target);
      //alert(event.target.textContent);
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [{
      name: 'Chuck Norris',
      power: Infinity
    }, {
      name: 'Bruce Lee',
      power: 9000
    }, {
      name: 'Jackie Chan',
      power: 7000
    }, {
      name: 'Jet Li',
      power: 8000
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: red
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

#search {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.js"></script>
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
          {{key | capitalize}}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]" @mouseover="mouseover">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search
    <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid :data="gridData" :columns="gridColumns" :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンク先を参照し勉強させていただきました。また、コメントでご指摘がある通り、急ぎで回答が欲しかったため、マルチポストしてしまいました。すみません。